# GMM and MFCC for language identification

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, mfcc, gmm

I am new to machine learning domain. Currently, I am trying to implement a audio language detection system, based on MFCC, delta, delta delta and Mel Spectrum Coefficients of any audio file. These features are extracted using librosa. Librosa returns a 2D matrix of MFCC's. The problem is that I want to train them on a Gaussian Mixture Model. The Sci-kit library takes the input in the format `(n_samples, n_features)`, but I have a D matrix of the form `(n_samples, n_mfcc, n_time)` as returned by `librosa.features.mfcc()`. How can i provide a 3D input to a GMM?

Also is there a way so that I can send all the 4 features mentioned above into the model?

Comment: I think you should provide a [n_samples x n_mfcc] matrix for each n_time.